# Function giving strange error?

Tags: function, lua

```
    function returnNumPlus1(num)
    return num + 1
end

print(returnNumPlus1(0))

print(returnNumPlus1(9000))

local func1 = returnNumPlus1
print(func1(11))
```

I was testing it to try to get it to work without error, but i always get the same error as i post below. Im fairly new to lua, so i hope i can get this to work :D
and gives off the error:

```
stdin:1: attempt to call global 'func1' (a nil value)
stack traceback
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

does anyone know why? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are running this code in lua REPL, you need to define `func1` as global rather than local as the local context is specific to each line execution in the REPL and is not available for the next line.

Try:

```
function returnNumPlus1(num)
    return num + 1
end

print(returnNumPlus1(0))

print(returnNumPlus1(9000))

func1 = returnNumPlus1
print(func1(11))
```

Comment: Or, put the whole thing inside `do` ... `end` block.